# If $\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{m'}{n'}$ are neighbours in the Farey sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions

If $\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{m'}{n'}$ are neighbours in the Farey sequence, how can I prove that $|mn'-nm'|=1$?

I know a proof by vectors, by I am trying to prove this by induction or other high school method, but I couldn't prove this.

Does anyone know another manner to prove this without vectors?

Thanks for antetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with nothing more than induction and solving a system of two equations in two unknowns.

For the induction step suppose that $\frac{a}b<\frac{c}d$ are neighbors in $F_n$ and that $bc-ad=1$. If $\frac{a}b$ and $\frac{c}d$ are neighbors in $F_{n+1}$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise there is some $\frac{k}\ell$ between $\frac{a}b$ and $\frac{c}d$ in $F_{n+1}$. Suppose that we can show that $\frac{k}\ell=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$; then

$$bk-a\ell=b(a+c)-a(b+d)=bc-ad=1$$

and

$$\ell c-kd=(b+d)c-(a+c)d=bc-ad=1\;,$$

as desired.

To show that $\frac{k}\ell=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$, note first that

$$\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac{a}b=\frac{bc-ad}{b(b+d)}>0$$

and

$$\frac{c}d-\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{bc-ad}{d(b+d)}>0\;,$$

so $\frac{a}b<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}d$.

In any case we can solve the system

$$\begin{align*}
&ax+cy=k\\
&bx+dy=\ell\;:
\end{align*}$$

multiplying the first equation by $d$ and the second by $c$ and subtracting the first from the second yields the equation

$$x=(bc-ad)x=c\ell-dk>0\;,$$

and similarly we find that $y=bk-a\ell>0$. (The inequalities follow from $\frac{a}b<\frac{k}\ell<\frac{c}d$.)

Thus, there are positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac{k}\ell=\frac{ax+cy}{bx+dy}$, which implies that $\ell=bx+dy\ge b+d$. In particular, if there is any fraction between $\frac{a}b$ and $\frac{c}d$ with a denominator less than or equal to $n+1$, it is their mediant $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$.

Comment: Great solution! But, how can I prove this gcd(ax+cy, bx+dy)=1? Thanks for atention.

Comment: @Cavalo: The quickest way is to note that since there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $bk-a\ell=1$, $k$ and $\ell$ must be relatively prime: any common divisor must also divide $1$.